# In Makie.jl how to avoid overlapping axis elements in repeated plot?

Tags: plot, julia, makie.jl

How do I avoid the overlapping elements in the axis when plotting multiple times (e.g. in a `for` loop) in Makie?

For example, here I'd like to show the many density lines, but the y-axis has overlapping elements. Why does this occur and how do I prevent it from happening?

```
f = Figure()
for i in 1:10
    ax = Axis(f[1, 1])
    density!(rand(20), color = (:red, 0.0),
strokecolor = :red, strokewidth = 1, strokearound = false)
    xlims!(0.0,1.0)
end
f
```

Produces:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create the axis once and use it as the first argument to `density!`:

```
f = Figure()
ax = Axis(f[1, 1])
xlims!(ax, 0.0, 1.0)
for i in 1:10
    density!(ax, rand(20), color = (:red, 0.0),
        strokecolor = :red, strokewidth = 1, strokearound = false)
end
f
```

Comment: Isn't it enough to call `xlims!` once?

Comment: Thanks, wasn't looking at that